# Wordpress - How to prevent stripping comments out of a template

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

I have a wordpress site that has to integrate with a .NET platform for a client. I simply need to add two commented out pieces of HTML for it to work on the .NET platform end (not our system).

Wordpress keeps stripping it out of the custom template, though. Is there a way around this?

Note: This is not done in the backend editor. This is directly in the template php file that I'm placing these two commented lines of code.

Also note: I already tried Linklays function to modify tinymce to see if that would be a solution, but again this isn't using tinymce since it's hard-coded into the template.

Comment: Can you share the custom template?

Comment: Check the solution posted here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312622/stop-wordpress-from-removing-html-comments-in-content

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does no processing at all on any hard coded HTML in the templates, therefore I suspect you probably have some kind of caching plugin active which minified the html or strips out the comments.

Some themes have these caching methods build into them so if you have no caching plugin active it might be a good idea to view the documentation of your theme for any caching methods and related settings.

Maybe also worth looking at the commented code, If you added the code in a PHP block and used a keyboard shortcut to do the comment it might have added it as a PHP comment instead of a HTML comment.

Answer (score 0):

For a comment in every page you can use the `wp_footer` hook. It will add your HTML to the footer of any page:

Here is the code rip you should add to your `functions.php` on your theme root directory, you can change it on your server or local project or via Administration Screens > Appearance > Editor:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'some_comments'); 
function some_comments() { 
    echo '<!-- Write your comments here -->'; 
}
```